# best method for improving compilattion speed in c++

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, cmake

I have a C++ project which has more than 50 classes. These classes can be categorized into 7 different folders but most of these classes are used in different parts of the code.
As I use Netbeans for development, It compiles and link all object files to each other. Consequently it links all files to others which take lots of time.
For removing this problem, I used CMake and tried to separately compile each category independently to dependent each category to all required ones. But after some time lots of "Undefined reference to ..." begins when I includes some headers in other modules.
The new solution which is proposed to me is creating a Facade class for each category which handles each category operation. But in order to remove include dependency, it was said that I can not use public functions of each categories classes. instead I have to get target object and give it to a function of Facade class to execute it for me in other classes. for example suppose this scenario:

```
ClassA.h:
            Class A{
                int calculateSomething(string str);
            }

  ClassA.cpp:
         int A::calculateSomething(string str){
              if(str="1") return 1;
         }

 ClassAFacade.h
            Class A; 


            Class AFacade{
                static int calculateSomething(Class A*, string str);    
                static A* getA();
            }

ClassAFacade.cpp
            #include "A.h" 

            int AFacade::calculateSomething(Class A*, string str){
                return A->calculateSomething(str);
            }

           A* AFacade::getA(){
                return new A();
            }


ClassB.h:
        #include "AFacade.h"

        Class B{
            void someMethod();
        }

 ClassB.cpp:
            #include "B.h"
        void B::someMethod(){
                 A* aptr = AFacade::getA();
                 int tmp = AFacade::calculateSomething(aptr,"test");
         }
```

Although this solution seems to resolve my issue but it is weird. because it actually is preventing function calls and is giving this permission to some specific class (7 categories Facade classes).
Do you think that this solution is correct? can you offer any better solution for solving this problem?

Comment: Look up PIMPL idiom.

Comment: Facade is to regroup some systems in a simpler interface. You may use interface for A to hide its internal.

Comment: most time-efficient method is to get a faster PC

Comment: although PIMPL idiom is similar to this issue but it has some differences. Such as usage scope. in my problem, I am hiding public methods from other consumers classes while PIMPL is hiding private variables to increase compilation speed. But by considering this idiom it means that you are suggesting my proposed solution.

Comment: Use Ninja instead of make, use Clang instead of GCC, use always the newest version of your compiler. Everything beside that, is a compromise between maintainability and compilation speed. Seldom it is a good idea to choose the latter.

Comment: Rather than try to program around the build problem you could look into building a `Makefile` that only compiles the elements that change. Also [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) and [distcc](https://github.com/distcc) can improve build performance.

Comment: 50 classes is small, not large.  Just how long is the compilation time you think is too long?  In other words, you must have some 'expected' build duration in mind based on your previous experience. So what duration did you actually measure?

Comment: It sounds like you should look into precompiled headers. As described, your project doesn't sound especially large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to write interfaces for all classes, which need to be visible outside a category. An interface in C++ is a pure abstract class. Also declare a factory method for each interface. In the implementation file for the factory method, include the actual implementation of the class:

```
// file: a_interface.h
namespace catA {
class AInterface {
  public:
    virtual ~AInterface() = default;
    int calculateSomething(string str) = 0;
};
std::unique_ptr<AInterface> createA();
}  // namespace catA

// file: a.h
include "a_interface.h"
namespace catA {
class A : public AInterface
{
  public:
    int calculateSomething(string str) override;
};
}  // namespace catA

// file: a_interface.cpp
#include "a.h"
namespace catA {
std::unique_ptr<AInterface> createA()
{
  return std::make_unique<A>();
}
}  // namespace catA

// file: a.cpp
#include "a.h"
namespace catA {
int A::calculateSomething(string str)
{
  // do stuff
}
}  // namespace catA
```

Then you can include `a_interface.hpp` everywhere you need the functionality of `A`, get an instance via `createA()` and don't have to deal with the implementation details:

```
#include "b.h"
#include "a_interface.h"
namespace catB {
void B::someMethod() {
  auto aptr = catA::createA();
  int tmp = aPtr->calculateSomething("test");
}
}  // namespace catB
```

With CMake you can then create separate shared (or static) libraries for each category with linkage between the appropriate libraries. Or you [create object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) without explicit linkage.
In both cases, you'll end up with separate make targets for each category. On code changes, *make* (or *Ninja* or whatever) will figure out the required targets to rebuild on its own.

Answer (score 0):

On my previous contract, a big project (mostly C++) with hundred's of developers and more than one million LOC (lines-of-code), the build times **in the morning** could usually 'rebuild all' in less than 1 hour.  By noon, the rebuild all often exceeded 3 hours.  Those compiles are spread across multiple machines, with fast network hardware.

This is also why you use Make files ... a well done Make file can avoid rebuilding what has not changed.

---

I offer that the best method(s) to improve build performance is to 1) work on your make files (and possibly build 'scripts', if you use them), and 2) distribute the build across as many processors / cores as you can.  3) Only use the fastest hardware (Ethernet) connections available between the computers and file servers.